# fill next 2 row with current row value pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a df such as

```
    df.head(8)
Out[105]: 
            Next_3rdF
Prev_3rdF            
1979-12-21 1980-02-15
1980-01-18 1980-03-21
1980-02-15 1980-04-18
1980-03-21 1980-05-16
1980-04-18 1980-06-20
1980-05-16 1980-07-18
1980-06-20 1980-08-15
1980-07-18 1980-09-19
```

starting from the first index, I want to fill the next 2 row with the first index value, then 4,5,6 with index 4 value and this pattern for the entire dataframe such as:

```
    df.head(8)
Out[105]: 
            Next_3rdF
Prev_3rdF            
1979-12-21 1980-02-15
1980-01-18 1980-02-15
1980-02-15 1980-02-15
1980-03-21 1980-05-16
1980-04-18 1980-05-16
1980-05-16 1980-05-16
1980-06-20 1980-08-15
1980-07-18 1980-08-15
```

any easy way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: if you just want to do just that then `df.iloc[1:3] = df.iloc[0]` and `df.iloc[5:] = df.iloc[3]` will work

Comment: @EdChu, the Dataframe has 4k rows, I guess I can loop over it but I am wondering if I can do this in a sexier way :)

Comment: But you've not explained this or whether this pattern is repeating etc.

Comment: @edChum, sorry, fixed.

Comment: Sorry are asking `df.iloc[1:3:3] = df.iloc[0::3]`? Actually the problem here is that you trying to assign to 2 rows at a time with a single scalar value each time, my suggested code snippet here won't work

Comment: yes doesn't work, thank for the help!

Comment: the other way would be to iterate over the index in steps of three and overwrite on each iteration for 4k rows, this may not be too slow. something like `for idx in df.iloc[::2].index: df.iloc[idx+1: idx+3] = df.iloc[idx]` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way thanks to @EdChum

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[1::3].values, index=df.iloc[1::3].index, columns=['arranged'])
df = df.join(df2).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Thank you!